# ¿Cómo obtener el nombre del key en un Objeto?

Tags: javascript

Buenas me veo en la necesidad de obtener el nombre de key de un Json en javascript, por ejemplo dado este:

```
var myVar = { test: {typeA: '501', typeB : '502' } };
```

Obtener el nombre de 'test'

Comment: Esto no es un json eso es un objeto

Comment: @aldanux cuando usar Object.keys?

Comment: @rn3w - [Ver ejemplo](http://jsbin.com/xolodap/edit?js,console)

Comment: @rn3w según la documentación hace lo mismo que el for in, con la diferencia que el for in enumera las propiedades y encadena las llamadas.

Comment: Por favor **no edites** la pregunta si no no tienen sentido las respuestas (excepto tuya)

Comment: @aldanux Pero si tu hubieses editado la pregunta desde un principio, porque coloque JSON y cometí un error debo editarla.

Comment: Esto sigue sin ser un JSON...

Comment: @Wilfredo creo que lo mejor a esta altura sería editar la palabra JSON y reemplazarla por "objeto".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

También puedes usar [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...in):

```js
var myVar = { typeA: '501', typeB: '502' };

for (var key in myVar) {
  
  console.log(key);
  console.log(myVar[key]);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Tenia que editar la respuesta ya que hubo cambios en la [pregunta original](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/40453/1):

```js
var myVar = { test: { typeA: '501', typeB : '502' } };

for (var key1 in myVar) {
  
  console.log(key1);   
  
  for (var key2 in myVar[key1]) {    
   
    console.log(key2);
    console.log(myVar[key1][key2]);
  }   
}
```

Comment: hola y si tuviera otro objeto adentro del objeto 'myVar', por ejemplo----> var myVar = { test: { typeA: '501', typeB : '502' } , exam: {typeb:'aaaa', typeb:'orale'}}. como obtengo ahora test y exam?

Answer (score 1):

Básicamente lo que se puede hacer, es usar el [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)(Documentación en Ingles) para obtener los valores que se deseen, por ejemplo:

```js
var miVariable = { test: {typeA: '501', typeB : '502' } };;
var resultado = Object.keys(miVariable)[0]; // Sera el valor del key test
alert(resultado);
```

Answer (score 0):

basandome en la respuesta de @aldanux

en el segundo ejemplo muestro los valores 501, 502...

```js
var myVar = { typeA: '501', typeB: '502' };

for (var key in myVar) {
  
  console.log(key);
}

var myVar = { typeA: '501', typeB: '502' };

for (var key in myVar) {
  
  console.log(myVar[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Te muestro dos formasmuy sencillas de obtener la propiedad test en Javascript.
Una forma es con un for y la otra con [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
var myVar = { test: {typeA: '501', typeB : '502' } };

// Ejemplo 1. Usando un for.
for(var propName in myVar) {
    if(propName === "test"){
        console.log("Nombre propiedad: ", propName, " y sus valores son: ", myVar[propName])
    }
}

// Ejemplo Object.keys()
var keyNames = Object.keys(myVar);
for (var i in keyNames) {
    if(propName === "test"){
         console.log("Nombre propiedad: ", propName, " y sus valores son: ", myVar[propName])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Otra opcion a lo que solicitas con [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Map) de `Javascript`

```js
var myVar = { test: {typeA: '501', typeB : '502' } };

Object.keys(myVar).map(function(key, index) {
    console.log(key);
});
```

Comment: hola y si tuviera otro objeto adentro del objeto 'myVar', por ejemplo----> var myVar = { test: { typeA: '501', typeB : '502' } , exam: {typeb:'aaaa', typeb:'orale'}}. como obtengo ahora test y exam?

Comment: @Afi02 el `.map` es un ciclo por lo tanto si agregas ese json a la variable la salida seria `test` y `exam` por lo tanto no habría modificación alguno el el código, si lo que quieres es obtener los valores internos tendrías que poner dentro del "map" otro `.map` lo cual obtendrías `typeA,typeB,typeb,typeb` según tu json, si casualmente no te funciona es porque en el segundo objeto tienes dos `key` con el mismo nombre y eso es un error. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

```js
 const myVar = { test: {typeA: '501', typeB : '502' } };

    for(const x in myVar){
      //hacemos una pequeña validacion que si exista esa clave
        if(myVar.hasOwnProperty(x)){
        //obtenemos las keys
         let dato = Object.keys(myVar[x])
         //mostramos
         console.log(dato);
        }
        
    }
```